# Question Regarding "Localhost says...." alert box

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Quick question, in our web application when I navigate to a page I get the "Localhost says:....."  I understand it is a security/anti-phishing feature, however it only occurs on one page and not the others.  What would cause the security popup for one page and not the other pages? Is it a browser setting?

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard.  This was added by our security team performing security testing.